# How to mitigate excessive ringing in VDS and VGS

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, emc, semiconductors, snubber

I have a few questions regarding my measurement results in the lab for a double pulse test setup. There are three issues which I want to mitigate
.

1. At turn-on interval, there is excessive ringing in V<sub>GS</sub> and V<sub>DS</sub> which could result into some serious EMI issues in our application hence lowering the overall efficiency of system.
2. At turn-off interval, the V<sub>DS</sub> spike is roughly 6 to 8 V higher than what it should be causing an increase in turn-off switching energy.
3. For diode reverse recovery, the V<sub>SD</sub> spike is also very high and in one instance it even surpassed the maximum blocking voltage capability of the device, but using a small scrubber circuit it is now below that value, but still very high for our application, which is probably why this device has higher reverse recovery energy.

The background of this activity is that this test is performed at 24 V and 10-60 A current with a 150 V, 150 A MOSFET [IXTH150N15X4](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=04a1d589-188f-49b6-a61c-88de951df765&filename=littelfuse-discrete-mosfets-n-channel-ultra-junction-ixt-150n15x4-datasheet). I have already increased the R<sub>G(on)</sub> and R<sub>G(off)</sub> from the original values and have added a snubber circuit as well between drain and source of the device under test.

I am new in this field so I don't have a lot of experience at the moment to figure out the root cause of these issues and do corrective measures. I will wait for your valuable feedback.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @RohatKılıç Schematic is attached  in question with ossilogram for 24V 10A. the spice schematic is exactly same as real schematic and Rgon and Rg off are 100 ohms

Comment: @mkeith Schematic is attached  in question with ossilogram for 24V 10A. the spice schematic is exactly same as real schematic and Rgon and Rg off are 100 ohms

Comment: These are good scope shots. Please also explain **HOW** you probed. At these levels of dI/dt and dV/dt, it is very easy to measure ghosts. If real, it looks like the dI/dt creates too much interference at your gate, which could be improved by reducing the gate resistors.

Comment: @tobalt Ch2: Rogowski probe 120A (20A/V) for I_shunt, Ch3: Vgs_Q2 (Passive probe x10)
, Ch4: Vds_Q2 (differential probe x100)

Comment: @Alison if you see the current oscillate with the Rogowski probe, then it is most likely real. Have you tried various lower (or even higher) gate resistors ?

Comment: @tobalt there is no issue in current. the transition is pretty much smooth. the issue is ringing in Vds, yes i tried with lower resistor as well, Rgon=30/50ohm and Rgoff=62/100 ohm but then at turn on we have some severe ringing in vds and Id both and persistent ringing with very higher magnitude then this

Comment: @Alison Oh I mixed that up. Well if current shows up smoothly, it means that the gate source voltage *cannot* be really zero or negative. It is super important to take the voltage probe ground from directly next to the probe point (max few mm away) and enclose *no loop* with the ground conductor at these high dI/dt

Comment: @tobalt so you think this is due to measurement error and Vds is not measured correctly?

Comment: @Alison Possibly. That or the Rogowski lacks the necessary bandwidth to show the ringing. Either current or voltage seem wrong because they don't agree

Comment: FYI, even with perfect probing, you're probably seeing Vds ringing of the opposite side FET [body diode] on Vgs, because the MOSFET itself has enough inductance, resistance and capacitance to mix together both modes i.e. the G-S and D-S loops are coupled internally so you see a bit of what's happening from each loop in the other. And the drive resistor is quite large too. Given the slowness here, it seems it's more likely just oscillation, so depends on layout and device properties. It is unusual I think to oscillate without a low impedance (usually capacitive) G-S loop, which is interesting.

Comment: Is this a differential measurement or single ended? I had run into issues where there was significant ground ringing which vanishes when measured with either a differential probe or taking the difference on a scope. Adding to what @TimWilliams mentioned, TO247 devices usually have 4-8nH lead inductance (actual values vary with device construction) in addition to the board-induced parasitics. check datasheet of IRP250N for ref